# Iterate over days, starting from x date through an end date

Tags: ruby, json, date

I need to start from, for example, January 1 2013, and "do some things" for each date, resulting in a JSON file for each date.

I have the "do some things" part worked out for a single date, but I'm having a hard time starting at a date and looping through to another end date.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can use ranges :

```
(Date.new(2012, 01, 01)..Date.new(2012, 01, 30)).each do |date|
  # Do stuff with date
end
```

or (see @awendt answer)

```
Date.new(2012, 01, 01).upto(Date.new(2012, 01, 30)) do |date|
  # Do stuff with date
end
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! How would I define the date format (01012013 - month day year)?

Comment: My bad @HunterMcMillen. user1034672 I don't get your question.

Comment: For each date in the range, I need to eventually print it in this format: `01012103`, coinciding with monthdayyear.

Comment: Try this : ``sprintf '%02d%02d%d',date.month, date.day, date.year``

Comment: Hmm, just tried that, and nothing's being returned. I replaced the `#Do stuff with date` with it.

Comment: ``sprintf`` only creates a string, call ``printf`` if you want to actually print the string

Answer (score 31):

You could use:

```
 first.upto(last) do |date|
```

where `first` and `last` are Date objects.

See what I did [here in a project of mine](https://github.com/awendt/recharge/blob/master/recharge.rb#L64), for example.