# How to loop through days, starting today and through a target date

Tags: ruby, loops, date

I tried using answers [for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590613/iterate-over-days-starting-from-x-date-through-an-end-date) but was not able to get something that worked.

I want to be able to loop through days, starting today and going up to a target date set for an object.

The target date is of type `Date`.

I have tried a few things, all variations on the answers above, this was last attempt.

```
count = 0
Time.now..goal.target_date do 
  count += 1
end
```

This does not loop through anything and returns 0 as the count.  Right now this is only in dev, with one object, so I know there are many days between now and the target (which is set for December 31 of this year).

I also tried this.

```
count = 0
Date.new(Time.now)..goal.target_date do |date|
  count += 1
end
```

Which returns the error `undefined method 'div' for 2018-10-06 17:23:41 -0500:Time`.  (Same error if I use `Date.today` just with `:DATE` instead of `:Time` at the end).

Can anyone help me get this to run the loop for each day between now and the target date?

Thanks!

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744683/ror-cant-iterate-from-datetime-timewithzone).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrote this one using de Date.upto() method and it worked... you just gotta make sure that 'goal.target_date' is also a valid instance of Date

```
require 'date'

from = Date.today
goto = from + 3

from.upto(goto) do |date|
  puts date
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need a loop? If not, try this:

```
count = (goal.target_date - Date.current).to_i
```

I hope it useful for you. :)